# FormControlName not working with ion-radio

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

***New:***

So I can get it to work withou a radio-group or withouth the right bindings. I can't get it to work with both.

This is allowed:

```
<div *ngFor="let column of row.controls.columns.controls; let j = index">
                <ion-list radio-group [formControlName]="'col'+j">
                    <ion-radio></ion-radio>
                </ion-list>
            </div>
```

But then I don't have a list with a radio-group, it doesn't matter what I change it will always break. If I move the list outside it breaks, move the formControlName it breaks. I really don't know how to get this to work.

I would think that this should be the way to go:

```
<ion-list radio-group>
            <div *ngFor="let column of columns; let j = index">
                <div [formControlName]="'col'+j">
                    <ion-radio></ion-radio>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-list>
```

But again the same error:

> Error: No value accessor for form control with path: 'rows -> 0 -> col0'

i =  the amount of rows I need.
j =  the amount of options/questions I need.

***Old:***

I am trying to use the ion-radio as a input field in a formgroup but it keeps giving me the error:

> No value accessor for form control with path ...

So I switched to an input with type="radio", but if I want to group those, I need to give them the same name, which I can't because I am using a *ngFor and otherwise my formControlName is not correct anymore.

Can anybody help me to get the ion-radio to work? It would look better and easier to group.

```
<ion-col radio-group class="radioGroup" col-6>
   <ion-col *ngFor="let column of columns; let j = index">
        <input value="X" formControlName="col{{j + 1}}" type="radio" />
        <!-- <ion-radio value="X"></ion-radio> -->
    </ion-col>
</ion-col>
```

Creation:

```
this.inspectionTableForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    header: this.formBuilder.group({
        title: [this.question.properties.header[0]],
        columns: this.formBuilder.array([
                    this.formBuilder.control('')
                ]),
        comments: ['']
    }),
    rows: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.initRow()
    ])
});

private initRow() {
    // Create the temp control
    let tempControl = this.formBuilder.group({
        title: '',
    });

    // Create an array for the columns
    let arr = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < this.question.properties["number-of-columns"]; index++) {
        // Push a control to the array and also one for the value on a higher level
        arr.push(this.columns[index])
        tempControl.addControl(`col${index}`, this.formBuilder.control('')) // Col-1-2-3
    };
    tempControl.addControl('columns', this.formBuilder.array(arr)) //Array

    // Check if we need to add the comment field
    if (this.question.properties["comment-field"]) {
        tempControl.addControl('comment', this.formBuilder.control(''))
    }
    return tempControl;
}
```

Edit semi working new code (thanks xrobert35):

```
<ion-col radio-group [formControlName]="'col'+i">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let column of row.controls.columns.controls">
        <ion-radio></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

This is what I get when I press the first option, then second and then third:

[image]

It updates the same col with some weird value. I think the problem is that I do not need i as index but j, but it breaks when I do that. Something like this:

```
<ion-col radio-group >
    <ion-item *ngFor="let column of row.controls.columns.controls; let j = index" [formControlName]="'col'+j">
        <ion-radio></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

> No value accessor for form control with path: 'rows -> 0 -> col0'

Comment: What error? I don't see any error message

Comment: Updated in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the directive formControlName with ion-radio cause you can only use it on a component which work with ngModel.

I understand that you want a list of ion-radio but only one value bind into the formGroup. So you can use a ion-list component like in the documentation ? and replace the [(ngModel)] by formGroupName

```
<ion-list radio-group formControlName="myFormGroupName">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Friends</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="friends" checked></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Family</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="family"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Enemies</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="enemies" [disabled]="isDisabled"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/

**New code**  Your html should look like something like this

```
<div [fromGroup]="inspectionTableForm">

<div *ngFor"let question of questions; let indexRow=index" class="row" formArrayName="rows">
   <span> {{question.libelle}} </span>
   <ion-list radio-group [formControlName]="'answer'+indexRow">
       <ion-item *ngFor="let answer of question.answers">
           <ion-label>{{answer.labelle}}</ion-label>
           <ion-radio [value]="answer.value"></ion-radio>
       </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   <textarea formControlName="comment">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: If I do it like that I still get no value changes

Comment: What do you mean by you get no value changes ?  the value of the control "myFormGroupName" is not updated in the formGroup ?

Comment: Yeah exactly ( I have updated OP with new code). If I use the formControlName it says: No value accessor found. If I only use the formArray there are no changes.

Comment: I think I don't understand what you are trying to do can you provide the "creation" of the FormGroup in the component ?  ion-radio is not a component that work with ngModel so you can't add formControlName it's normal. I don't understand what you are trying to do with those radio, you try to use it like a checkbox ?

Comment: I am trying to create a "dynamic" table. Where you can specify the columns (up to 3) and as many rows as you like. 

Each row will have a header, 1-3 radio-buttons (options) and an optional comment field. So each row is basically a question, you can select an answer (one radio button) and maybe add a comment.

I will add the creation to the OP.

Comment: Up to 3 option columns, with the header and optional comment field that is a max of 5 columns.

Comment: ok so   : [text header] [ answer radio 1] [answser radio 2] [answer radio 3] [ textarea comment]  and you can select only one answer

Comment: Yeah exactly, I will add a screenshot to the OP with the ''final'' table. So a result row would be header, '', ''. 'X', comment for example

Comment: Thanks man, finally got it to work now! It does mix up the values, I think it has something to do with the binding!

Comment: mix up the values ?

Comment: Yeah it's using the i as an index, it should use the j. But however I try to set it to J, it will always say no value accessor. Check OP

Comment: i dont understand why you try to put a formControlName for each radio :   each group of radio  =  one formControlName  since you only need one with which is the selected answer. Futhermore like I told you, you can't add formControlName on something else that a component which work with [(ngModel)] so it will never work on a div. Why don't you add ion-item arround you ion-radio like in the code I gave you ?

Comment: I thought I needed a control for each radio button I used. I will try it with the ion-item.

Comment: I've tried adding `<ion-list radio-group formControlName='userType'>` & added 2 `<ion-item>`s inside the list, but I get "No value accessor for form control with name" error message

Answer (score 4):

if you have array of input and you use reactive methode it's better to use `FormArray` inside ur `FormGroup` instead of use this way .
this documentation will be help you to implement `FormGroup` in ur code :
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: I converted it to an array but I still don't get any values.