# how to use ion-radio in radio-group with ngfor?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am developing an starter IONIC app. Now I need to know how to use ion-radio inside of ngfor

I tried - [FormControlName not working with ion-radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333433/formcontrolname-not-working-with-ion-radio)

but doesn't worked.

1) try 1

```
<ion-list  radio-group formControlName="manufacturers">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let list of listArr; let i = index">
        <ion-label>{{list.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio  [value]="list.name"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

2) try 2

```
<ion-list  radio-group >
      <ion-item *ngFor="let list of listArr; let i = index">
        <ion-label>{{list.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-radio formControlName="manufacturers" [value]="list.name"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Ts file

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.listArr = [{ name: 'cucumber', checked: 'false' }, { name: 'Sausage', checked: 'false' }, { name: 'Pepperoni', checked: 'false' }, { name: 'Mushrooms', checked: 'false' }];
    // console.log(this.listArr);

    this.new_item_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      listName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      manufacturers: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

Results:
In case of Try 1-
NewItemPage.html:23 ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'manufacturers' at _throwError (forms.js:1732)

In case of try 2-
No error but all are selected default.

Comment: can you add the ts for this? where have you defined the formGroup?

Comment: [edit] your post with the information. Please dont add in the comment section